# Add local file URL handling to Applescript Application

Tags: applescript, defaults, automation, fluid.app

I am using a simple applescript application to open different URL schemes in different [Fluid Apps](http://fluidapp.com).

By setting this app as the default browser, I can effectively parse out the URL scheme and open the appropriate stand-alone Fluid App as the browser.

Everything works perfectly, except the "share this folder..." option in Dropbox.  This opens a local URL - `file:///var/folders/...`

This simply does not work.  The default_browser application launches and then immediately closes.

Does anyone know how to update this script so that local file links will work?

```
on open location this_URL

if this_URL contains "docs.google.com" then
    tell application "/Applications/Fluids/Google Drive.app"
        activate
        open location this_URL
    end tell
else if this_URL contains "drive.google.com" then
    tell application "/Applications/Fluids/Google Drive.app"
        activate
        open location this_URL
    end tell
else if this_URL contains "mail.google.com" then
    tell application "/Applications/Fluids/Gmail.app"
        activate
        open location this_URL
    end tell
else if this_URL contains "gmail.com" then
    tell application "/Applications/Fluids/Gmail.app"
        activate
        open location this_URL
    end tell
    -- default browser here
else
    tell application "/Applications/Google Chrome.app"
        activate
        open location this_URL
    end tell
end if
end open location
```

EDIT: to clarify - the Dropbox "share this folder..." option opens the default browser app (above), which then closes immediately.

Comment: I think the problem is that you're inside an `on open location` handler, while `this_URL` in the Dropbox-case would be recognized as a POSIX file, not a "location", though I'm not completely sure. Have you tried the above inside a `on run` event that checks whether `this_URL` contains `file://`? And what happens if you do a `display dialog` inside the `on open location` with a file-URL, does it even get catched by the event?

Comment: You're right - display dialog doesn't even work within that event. Which leads back to my initial question which is 'how do I add local file URL handling to this app?'  Any ideas?

Comment: So after googling' around for a bit I'm quite certain that re-routing the `file://` protocol is not possible. There's no LSHandlerURLScheme in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist` that maps this URL to the Finder - my guess is that the recognition of the `file:` protocol is deep inside the System resources and I wouldn't want to mess with that. What's the problem with the current handling of Dropbox's file URLs anyway? Where do you want to redirect this to?

Comment: The issue is for this applescript to work with any URLs it needs to be set as the default browser.  Nothing is wrong with the typical handling - that's what I'm trying to get back to.  does that make sense?  I updated the question with more info